# Unable to find exact cause of error in logcat

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I need help in locating which line in the logcat is indicating the error causing my app to terminate abruptly

This is what the Run tab shows at the time of app termination:

```
05/09 12:00:25: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /Users/---/myfolder/---/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop app.package.name
$ adb shell am start -n "app.package.name/app.package.name.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 6037 on device samsung-sm_g925k-05157df5155ecb08
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/ViewRootImpl@fb453bc[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@fb453bc[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 1924 for frameCount 3848
I/AudioTrack: updateAudioTranstionLength FadeIn[0] FadeOut[0] FadeInRing[0]
I/TMSDISP: AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl::~AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl - Enter
    AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl::~AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl - Enter2
    AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl::~AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl - mSource2
    AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl::~AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl - Exit
Application terminated.
```

I can consistently make the app terminate in the same manner. The app's user interface loads without problem and it accepts button press inputs as expected before termination. However, looking at the logcat I am not able to find which message it is exactly that is indicating a reason for the app termination. Sorry for the long logcat message but I could really appreciate some help at this point. **The full logcat with no filters is given below**:

https://pastebin.com/f6BSxJXx

Searching for `AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl::~AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl - Enter` (from the run tab) in the logcat shows that this set of messages has appeared multiple times, and I am assuming the last time it appeared in the logcat should closer to when the app terminated. However looking at logcat messages below and above this set of messages is not giving me any ideas what the possible cause for the app termination could be.

How can I determine the exact cause for app termination from this logcat message? This app uses NDK as well. There are no error messages or dialog box, the simply closes. Does android store any other logs detailing the reason for app closure?

Using Samaung Galaxy 6, Android 7.0, Android Studio 3.4 on Mac notebook

Comment: Have you tested this on other phones too or this happens only on Galaxy 6? Also, can you capture the logs from "Logcat" tab instead of "run"?

Comment: @RahulShukla  it happens in other phones as well. The full logcat is in the pastebin link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app terminating abruptly with no comprehensible error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964607/android-app-terminating-abruptly-with-no-comprehensible-error-message)

Comment: when I search for `AcsAndroidVirtualDisplayIntfImpl`, I can only find `Xamarin` ...

Comment: @Martin I don't know about that but I don't use xamarin in my app

Comment: Is it possible to share the APK or a sample app to reproduce the case?